# Is there a word for the patches of forest without significant understory?

Tags: single-word-requests

I am writing a story set mostly in a forest. One of the major location types in this story are the small patches of the forest that are dominated by the trees, and have a minimal amount of understory, so that they are easier to get through

I have yet had no luck in finding any relevant words for this idea. An example sentence could be "We walked along the new path until we reached the wide brown ______"

The word should ideally refer specifically to this concept, but I can accept more generic terms that refer to patches of a forest. The word should also not be so technical

Comment: It's usually coniferous forests that don't have plants growing under the trees, because ground covered in pine-needles etc. isn't suitable for the growth of other types of plants.

Comment: @KateBunting … and beech woods, which suppress almost everything underneath. But this thought is secondary to the main question.

Comment: @Anton - I meant that it depends on the type of woodland rather than being a distinct area in a forest.

Comment: @KateBunting agreed. I merely add beech for completeness.

Comment: I think of “deep” forest as having no understory.

Comment: Brown?  Anyway, I'd use the same words you did in your question, to make sure the reader understands what you're trying to say.  I think that "grove" might not be taken to mean *wooded area without understory.* / Maybe "parklike" would get the idea across, though.

Comment: "Normal"?  Where I live, forests without understory are the common situation.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I really do not believe *grove* answers this question; it says nothing about the presence or absence of an understory.  It's just a stand of trees. I know groves of aspen with plenty of understory, and I know groves of pines with no understory at all. If you are looking for an opening in the canopy, then you're talking about a *glade* not a *grove*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A **grove** is a small wooded area without significant understory (undergrowth, underbrush).

> A grove can be an orchard or a clump of trees that doesn't have much undergrowth and occupies a contained area, like an orange grove or a small shady grove of oak trees where you can have a picnic.
>
> [Vocabulary.com](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/grove)

Other dictionary definitions of *grove* (for the sense that is not an orchard):

> a small wood or forested area, usually with no undergrowth:
> *a grove of pines.* 
>  - *[Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/grove)*
>
> a small wood without underbrush 
>  - *[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/grove)*

It is rather a peculiar word as it is not found in any other Germanic language and it appears to have no cognates.

*[OED](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/81891?redirectedFrom=grove#eid)* provides the below for the etymology:

> Old English *gráf* masculine and neuter < prehistoric **graiƀo-* . Compare [greave](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/81124#eid2412692) *n.*<sup>*1*</sup>

Comment: I think the "without significant understory" implication arises from the fact that (as defined by the full OED), a ***grove*** is *a group of trees **affording shade** or forming **avenues or walks**, occurring naturally or planted for a special purpose*. As opposed to a ***thicket*** (into which small animals can run & hide - but not the people hunting them, because of all that low-level vegetation).

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grove_(nature)

Comment: It would be helpful to add Merriam Webster’s definition of grove, which suits perfectly.

Comment: But I don’t think a grove is a part of a larger wooded area.  It is a distinct stand of trees not surrounded by other trees.

Comment: A grove is normally not part of a larger wooded area and I think the context in OP doesn't have to have that strong connotation. Although, I found some usages online like "grove in a forest", mostly in some novels or ecology related books. An example could be: "We walked far into the woods and reached to this secluded oak grove."

Comment: @FumbleFingers I've never in my life imagined a grove to be a stand of trees without underbrush. Some groves have plenty of understory; others have none.  Presumably this is why [the OED makes no mention of this notion of lacking an understory](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/81891). The only naturally occurring groves that have no understory are those with a closed canopy such as those of redwoods or ancient pines. Deliberately cleared areas are something else.

Comment: @tchrist: It's not quite as absolute as the fact that all petrels are stormy, all dudgeon is high, and all fettle is fine. But a century or two ago, [*a measurable proportion* of all groves](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a+shady+grove%2Ca+grove&year_start=1750&year_end=1850&corpus=26&smoothing=3) were ***shady*** - as explicitly indicated by that OED definition. If you couldn't actually get *into* the grove because of the undergrowth, there wouldn't be much point in calling attention to the potential shade it offered (to wildlife?).